# Howto draw horizontalBar with dynamic thickness (automatic rescale on browser window height resize) in Chart.js 2.9.3?

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js

I use latest Chart.js **2.9.3**.

I'm trying to draw a horizontal bar with thickness that depends on browser window size: from **50** when browser window is fullscreen, to **20** when browser window is resized to very small height.

I've tried the following code - but bar is always **50** (https://jsfiddle.net/zg6c54rt/1/):

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
                datasets: [{
                    barThickness: 'flex',
                    maxBarThickness: 50,
                    data: [100, 90, 85, 95]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                 scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
     <div class="text-center">
            <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Changing `barThickness: 'flex',` to `barThickness: 20,` makes bar always **20**.

Not defining barThickness results in bar is always **50** (same as `barThickness: 'flex'`).

Howto draw horizontalBar with dynamic thickness?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `barThickness`, you could define [`categoryPercentage` together with `barPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage)

```
datasets: [{
  categoryPercentage: 1, 
  barPercentage: 0.5,
  data: [100, 90, 85, 95]
}]
```

> [`categoryPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration): Percent (0-1) of the available width each category should be within the sample width.
>
> [`barPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration): Percent (0-1) of the available width each bar should be within the category width. 1.0 will take the whole category width and put the bars right next to each other.

Comment: Hmm, I see no difference (horisontalBar height doesn't change on window height resize) - https://jsfiddle.net/pd0Lxzmc/